# PowerShell script to check which browsers are running

Tags: powershell

I would like to PowerShell script to check the open browsers on the computer, for this I was thinking to use "Get-Process" so it looks like that

```
if (Get-Process iexplore) { $iexplore = "Internet Explorer; " } else { $iexplore = "Internet Explorer is not running" }
if (Get-Process MicrosoftEdge) { $MicrosoftEdge = "Microsft Edge; " } else { $MicrosoftEdge = "Microsft Edge is not running" }
if (Get-Process msedge) { $msedge = "Microsft Edge(Chromium based); " } else { $msedge = "Microsft Edge Chromium based is not running" }
if (Get-Process chrome) { $chrome = "Google Chrome; " } else { $chrome = "Google Chrome is not running" }
if (Get-Process firefox) { $firefox = "Firefox; " } else { $firefox = "Firefox is not running" }
```

However, it is working until we do not consider Microsoft browsers as the process may still be in the background even if the browser is not opened. Is there a way to make sure that the result is correct and it is actually checking if the specific browser is opened?

Comment: ```if (Get-Process iexplore |  ? {$_.hasexited -eq $False})``` Shows processes that have not exited... See if this works

Comment: getting the same reusults

Comment: So are they correct?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the same result as before, so msedge is pretty much running all the time on windows 10 due to other system processes, so it always displays as the browser is opened even though it is not. Yes I modified that part to "if (Get-Process msedge"

Comment: In Edge itself you can tell it not to run in the background when closed.  Settings > System > "Continue running background apps when Microsoft Edge is closed".  Once you do that the processes will clear out a short while after closing Edge.

Comment: @Steven, i do not have this setting on my windows/edge version

Comment: That's Chromium Edge.  I don't have access to the old Edge at this point to check for a similar setting.  It might be there considering MS thought to put it in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your system you could get different results. But if you follow similar approach you could get the same result:

**Edge is open**:

```
Get-Process | ? {$_.ProcessName -like "*Edge*"}
```

outputs:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                   
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------                   
   1129      58    27444      89468       1,06  13408   2 MicrosoftEdge                 
   1124     109   127456     170436       2,47   2376   2 MicrosoftEdgeCP               
    504      22     6032      27156       0,13   8224   2 MicrosoftEdgeCP               
    501      21     6048      27076       0,08   9368   2 MicrosoftEdgeCP               
   1153     114   155548     208292       3,81  12084   2 MicrosoftEdgeCP               
    292      15     5280      16952       1,17  10232   2 MicrosoftEdgeSH
```

**Edge is closed**:

```
Get-Process | ? {$_.ProcessName -like "*Edge*"}
```

outputs:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                   
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------                   
    825      46    21544      69512       0,39   8976   2 MicrosoftEdge                 
    324      16     4636      19852       0,13   2388   2 MicrosoftEdgeCP               
    265      14     4000      14340       0,05   8924   2 MicrosoftEdgeSH
```

**solution**:

```
if ((Get-Process MicrosoftEdgeCP -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object).Count -gt 1){write-host "edge is open"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use "MainWindowHandle" as filter.

```
Get-Process -Name '*edge*' | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowHandle -gt 0 }
```

Comment: This should do the trick. If there is no mainwindowhandle present there is no visible window.